# Which pattern is better for KMP and why?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

Out of the following 2 patterns which one would perform better with respect to the KMP algorithm?

Pattern1 = PQRSTUV
Pattern2 = PPPPPPP

Answer (score 1):

we have to consider two cases

**case 1(There exists prefix of pattern 1 in the Text)**

[image]

Pattern 1 and pattern 2 gives the same number of  comparisons

**case 2(There exists prefix of pattern 2 in the Text)**

[image]

Here also pattern 1 and pattern 2 gives the same number of comparisons.

So pattern 1 and pattern 2 both runs in same way.